# while loop got stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was told to convert this 'For' Loop into 'while' :

```
 sequence = [1, 2, None, 4, None, 5]
total = 0
for value in sequence:
    if value is None:
        continue
    total += value
print (total)
```

This is the while loop

```
sequence = [1, 2, None, 4, None, 5]
total = 0
i=0
while i < len(sequence):
    if sequence[i] is None:
        print('None')
        continue
    else :
        total += sequence[i] 
    i=+1
print (total)
```

the 'For' loop gives as a result 12

But it got stuck in the while loop

Comment: `i = +1` just sets `i` to `1` every time.  You want `i += 1`, which is short for `i = i + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert *any* `for` loop into a `while` loop without regard for the type of sequence being iterated.

```
seq_iter = iter(sequence)
total = 0
while True:
    try:
        value = next(seq_iter)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    if value is None:
        continue
    total += value
print(total)
```

This depends only on `sequence` supporting the iterator protocol (which is a requirement of the `for` loop), not on the sequence having indices that you can increment.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can convert your for loop into a while loop:

```
sequence = [1, 2, None, 4, None, 5]
total = 0
j = 0
while j < len(sequence):
    if sequence[j] is not None:
        total += sequence[j]
    j += 1
print(total)
```

The error was that you used `=+` instead of `+=`

Answer (score 0):

Variation on a theme:

```
sequence = [1, 2, None, 4, None, 5]
total = 0
seq = iter(sequence)
while True:
    try:
        if (nv := next(seq)) is not None:
            total += nv
    except StopIteration:
        break
print(total)
```

**Output:**

```
12
```

**Note:**

Requires Python 3.8+